# Добавление превью картинки к видео в iframe

Tags: html, iframe

В iframe загружается видео  `<iframe width="585" height="345" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/пыщпыщ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>` 
Можно ли добавить в него в качестве превью свою картинку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно взять [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com) и с его помощью загружать видео с YouTube в стандартный html5 `<video>`. А там уже просто `poster=путь_к_картинке`

```html
<video width="500" controls poster="http://datakogda.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Kogda-vyydet-Policeyskiy-s-Rublevki-3-na-TNT.jpg">
  <source type="video/youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apgClat2bMg">
</video>
```

Comment: картинка добавилась, но видео не воспроизводится

Comment: Mediaelement.js нужно подключить